# Remove item from Context Menu

Tags: finder, snow-leopard, services, shortcut-menu

I noticed extra options pop up in my context menus, I'm not sure how I managed to get it (or how long ago I installed this item), but does anyone know how I can remove it? Particularly the iconStiX item, which doesn't work.
I've tried looking in /Library/Context Menu Items, but there's nothing there

+1 if you can tell me where it came from.

[image: Context menu that I'm trying to kill]

Comment: These are Services. Normally they are under a "Services" submenu, but if you only have a few they are at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just installed and then uninstalled iconStiX again - just to see where the stuff was placed.

The uninstall is like this *(see Readme.pdf in iconStiX.dmg)*:

> Throw away the following 4 items into the Trash:

- the **iconStiX** program in your `Applications` folder (or any other place of your choice)
- in your `~/Library/Preferences`:

  - `li.loos.trollin.iconStiX.plist`
  - `li.loos.trollin.iconStiX.LSSharedFileList.plist` (if any)
- a folder named **`iconStiX`** in your `~/Library/Application Support` folder

> Empty the Trash.

BUT this doesn't remove the Contextual Menu Items - unless you **reboot** your Mac *(I did that, and the items was gone)*.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat your answer

Comment: @Loïc Wolff Looking good - now :o)

Answer (score 3):

You can modify what's in your right-click context menus going to Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services and unchecking the services there.

Answer (score 1):

Look into

- `~/Library/Contextual Menu Items`
- `/Library/Contextual Menu Items` folders
- `~/Library/Services`
- `/Library/Services`

To access them, open a Finder icon, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, or `Go` > `Go to Folder` and paste one of the two paths above.

You'll find there all the contextual menu extensions and your services. Move them to the folder to disable them.
You may need to Log Out/In to apply the changes.

Comment: The menu item can also be controlled from a script in `~/Library/Services` and/or `/Library/Services`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but: ~/Library/Contextual Menu Items - I don't have this folder; /Library/Contextual Menu Items - this folder is empty; ~/Library/Services - I don't have this folder; /Library/Services - I don't have this folder; /System/Library/Services - there's nothing in here that seems relevant. Any ideas?